# Building phonegap code in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I am reading [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html) like to configure my PC. In the section 5

**The blackberry directory contains two directories, sample and www. The sample folder contains a complete Cordova project. Copy the sample folder to another location on your computer.**

I have downloaded latest phonegap from [here](http://phonegap.com/install/). It does not contain any folder like sample and www.

How can I do it???

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the guide you are reading,  It's the Guide for installing PhoneGap version 2.3.  The latest version of PhoneGap is 3.x+

[Download](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/2.3.0.zip) version 2.3 to use with what you're reading.